# Query con .filter() utlizando una lista como filtro

Tags: python, django

Tengo 2 modelos:

Un Modelo llamado Follow que contiene "follower" y "followed". Ya tengo en un array llamado iFollowed que contiene una select de todos las filas del Follow que me interesan (todos los Follow cuyo follower soy yo mismo).

Por otro lado un modelo llamado Post que contiene "author" y "text".

Necesito hacer un select de los Post cuyo author sean los followed de la lista iFollowed. ¿Cómo se podría hacer?

**model>Post:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**model>Follow:**

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    followed = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

**view>HomeView:**

```
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "home/index.html"
    form_class = AddPostForm
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        myid = self.request.user
        print(myid.id)
        seguidor = Follow.objects.filter(follower=myid.id)
        print(seguidor)
          context['posts']=Post.objects.all().filter(author_id__in=seguidor.followed)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "home/index.html"
    login_url = reverse_lazy('account_login')
    form_class = AddPostForm
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        myid = self.request.user
        ifollowerAndFollowedQuery = Follow.objects.filter(follower=myid.id)
        followedList = ifollowerAndFollowedQuery.all().values_list('followed')
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all().filter(author_id__in=followedList).order_by('-id')
        return context
```

Comment: ¿esto es una respuesta o una aclaración a la pregunta? como solo tiene código sin ninguna explicación... si es una respuesta debería estar explicda. si es una aclaración no debería estar en la zona de respuestas (puedes editar la pregunta)